# Certain names do not exist in current context in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a unity script that plays dialogue using the third party program Ink. and when I attempt to run the program these three errors constantly appear:

Assets\C# Scripts\DialogueManager.cs(37,13): error CS0103: The name 'InputManager' does not exist in the current context
Assets\C# Scripts\DialogueManager.cs(57,13): error CS0103: The name 'current' does not exist in the current context
Assets\C# Scripts\DialogueManager.cs(57,13): error CS0103: The name 'current' does not exist in the current context

and here's the code itself below; it's a couple lines long but the error messages show the relevant lines:

```
1 using System.Collections;
2 using System.Collections.Generic;
3 using UnityEngine;
4 using TMPro;
5 using Ink.Runtime;
6 
7 public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
8 {
9     [Header("Dialogue UI")]
10    [SerializeField] private GameObject dialoguePanel;
11     [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI dialgoueText;
12 
13     private Story currentStory;
14     private bool dialogueIsPlaying;
15 
16     private static DialogueManager instance;
17 
18    private void Awake()
19     {
20         instance = this;
21     }
22     public static DialogueManager GetInstance()
23     {
24         return instance;
25     }
26    private void Start()
27     {
28         dialogueIsPlaying = false;
29         dialoguePanel.SetActive(false);
30     }
31     private void Update()
32     {
33         if (!dialogueIsPlaying)
34         {
35             return;
36         }
37         if (InputManager.GetInstance(). GetSubmitPressed())
38         {
39             ContinueStory();
40        }
41     }
42 
43     public void EnterDialogueMode(TextAsset inkJSON)
44     {
45         currentStory = new Story(inkJSON.text);
46         dialogueIsPlaying = true;
47         dialoguePanel.SetActive(true);
48 
49     }
50     private void ExitDialogueMode()
51     {
52         dialogueIsPlaying = false;
53        //SCENE MANAGER GO OFF SCENE TO WORLD
54    }
55     private void ContinueStory()
56     {
57         if (current.Story.canContinue)
58         {
59             dialogueText.text = currentStory.Continue();
60         }
61         else
62         {
63             ExitDialogueMode();
64         }
65     }
66 }
```

I've got no idea how to fix this issue and am pretty new to coding so help would be much appriciated!

Comment: It can't find `InputManager`.  Where is that defined?

Comment: Perhaps you should use `currentStory` where you have `current`?

Comment: Are you using Input System package?

Comment: Yeah, im using unitys old input system package, I don't want to enable the new one because it'll mess with stuff already in the program, most of this code is copied from places and I thought that people using the new input system might mess with it, you think that could be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to A. Define `InputManager`, and B. you should change `current` to `currentStory`

That may not be the only issue, but that will be a start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem (Line **57**):

you wrote **current.Story.canContinue** instead of **currentStory.canContinue**

```
private void ContinueStory()
56     {
57         if (current.Story.canContinue)
58         {
59             dialogueText.text = currentStory.Continue();
60         }
61         else
62         {
63             ExitDialogueMode();
64         }
65     }
```